# When opened from mobile website, the migration site icons are extra large

Tags: bug, design, migration, mobile-web

On my Nexus 4 running Chrome browser, if I choose to migrate a question using the Vote To Migrate dialog box, the icons of destination sites are huge.

[image]

Comment: Clearly this is a nod to us fat-fingered folks. Big icons == big targets.

Comment: Well, in the full site theme there's a CSS rule restricting size to 58px while in mobile theme it's 90% so the root of the bug is quite clear.

Comment: Still reproduces, some years later